# Use BeautifulSoup to get youtube description?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a python function that takes in a youtube url video link and returns the description (if it exists) as a string with all non-ascii characters replaced with a space. I'm having some trouble getting it to work though.

Anyone got any ideas. I think that `<p id="eow-description" ></p>` is used in all videos to hold the description but I can't figure out how to have it return just an entire string, formatted how we see it and not how it's formatted in the page source.

I'm using these 2 videos to test it with and without descriptions.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHvccEXfacM

```
video_source = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0")
parsed_soup = BeautifulSoup(video_source.content)
print parsed_soup.find_all("p", {"id": "eow-description"})[0]
```

I don't know how to go about formatting that into a string.

Comment: Can u show us your code so far?

Comment: Have you considered using the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos)? It allows you to get info on several videos at a time with the `/list` endpoint, and the returned information includes the description.

Comment: Otherwise, please show us your actual code, perhaps you have a mistake in it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you check if i have done it right :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters hahah , nvm

Comment: Code added, the api looks like it would be easier, but I'm not that familar with setting it up. @MartijnPieters

Comment: @MohitBhasi: You didn't do it right, I am afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be much better off using the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos), there is a `list` endpoint that'll return detailed information for one or more ids *per API call*.

Grab yourself an API key (see the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application), for a script on your on computer use a server API key) and the [Python client libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/); install these with `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`.

Then listing descriptions can be done with:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build

DEVELOPER_KEY = '<API key provided by Google>'
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

ids = '9bZkp7q19f0,eHvccEXfacM'
results = youtube.videos().list(id=ids, part='snippet').execute()
for result in results.get('items', []):
    print result['id']
    print result['snippet']['description']
    print '-----'
```

Demo:

```
>>> from apiclient.discovery import build
>>> DEVELOPER_KEY = '<get your own key here>'
>>> youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
>>> ids = '9bZkp7q19f0,eHvccEXfacM'
>>> results = youtube.videos().list(id=ids, part='snippet').execute()
>>> for result in results.get('items', []):
...     print result['id']
...     print result['snippet']['description']
...     print '-----'
... 
9bZkp7q19f0
▶ Watch HANGOVER feat. Snoop Dogg M/V @
http://youtu.be/HkMNOlYcpHg

PSY - Gangnam Style (강남스타일) 
▶ Available on iTunes: http://Smarturl.it/psygangnam
▶ Official PSY Online Store US & International : http://psy.shop.bravadousa.com/
▶ About PSY from YG Ent.: http://smarturl.it/YGfamilyAboutPSY
▶ PSY's Products on eBay: http://stores.ebay.com/ygentertainment
▶ YG-eShop: http://www.ygeshop.com

For More Information @
http://www.facebook.com/officialpsy
http://twitter.com/psy_oppa
http://twitter.com/ygent_official
http://me2day.net/psyfive
http://www.psypark.com
App Store: http://goo.gl/l9TU6
Google Play: http://goo.gl/UiEn1

© YG Entertainment Inc. All rights reserved.
-----
eHvccEXfacM

-----
```

Comment: What do I do for step 5 in the instructions you linked?

Comment: @Johnny use an API key; my code names it `DEVELOPER_KEY`.

Comment: @Johnny: sorry; I already had an API key and long forgot there are different types. I'd use a server API key for a script.

Answer (score 1):

Beautifulsoup is quite slow , best way is to use [Google's YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) as suggested in the comments. It is much simpler:

```
def PrintEntryDetails(entry):
    print 'Video description: %s' % entry.media.description.text
```

*Not what you want , let me know*